# nothing is displayed on the page with all products in Django

Tags: django

There is a model with three classes of category-subcategory-products

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name_category = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'name cat', max_length = 100, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="media/", verbose_name='pic')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=160, unique=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_category


class Subcategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='категория', related_name='sub')
    name_subcategory = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'name subcat', max_length = 100, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="media/", verbose_name='pic')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=160, unique=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_subcategory


class Product(models.Model):
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='категория',related_name='prod')
    name_product = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'name product', max_length = 100, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="media/", verbose_name='pic')
    price = models.IntegerField('price')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_product
```

views.py

```
class CategoryView(ListView):
    """all category"""
    model = Category


class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    """all sub category"""
    model = Category
    

class SubcategoryView(ListView):
    """all product"""
    model = Subcategory
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.CategoryView.as_view()),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='category_detail'), 
    path('<slug:slug>/<slug:slug_sub>/', views.SubcategoryView.as_view(), name='subcategory_list'),
]
```

page template from which I go to the page with all products (category_detail.html)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %} 
<h2>{{ category.name_category }}</h2>
   {% for sub in category.sub.all %}
      <a href="{% url 'subcategory_list' slug=category.slug slug_sub=sub.slug %}"> {{sub.name_subcategory}}</a>
      <img src="{{sub.image.url}}" width="100px" height="100px">
   {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

page template (subcategory_list.html) with all products (here I did not write the output of the products because even the name of the subcategory is not transmitted)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %} 
    {{sub.name_subcategory}}
{% endblock %}
```

I just can’t understand why it doesn’t display anything on the last page. Perhaps the problem is in the classes in views since previously tried to write only through functions

Comment: Which folder are your templates?

Comment: @HigorRossato templates/catalog

Comment: @HigorRossato But this is hardly important here, because information is not displayed only in the last template

Comment: You don't have `sub` in the Context here: `{{sub.name_subcategory}}`

Comment: @Borut in `SubcategoryView(ListView)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, on DetailView, Django sends an `object` to the context and therefore that's what you should access in your template. You can see it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %} 
<h2>{{ object.name_category }}</h2>
   {% for sub in object.sub.all %}
      <a href="{% url 'subcategory_list' slug=object.slug slug_sub=sub.slug %}"> {{ sub.name_subcategory }}</a>
      <img src="{{ sub.image.url }}" width="100px" height="100px">
   {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

You also will need a `SubCategoryDetailView` if you want to see details of that. If you want to override how Django passes data to the context, you can declare `context_object_name` with whatever you like. Please also have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/)

Comment: just the same in this template everything is deducing from me. problems in
`{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block content%}
    {{sub.name_subcategory}}
{% endblock%}`

Comment: Please, look at the variables being printed in the template. As @borut said in his comment, you don't have `sub` being passed to the context. Unless you override the `get_context_data` and set that variable there, you won't have it